# Imparfait de narration : Emploi du verbe mourir à l'imparfait (il mourait)

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, littérature, passé-composé, imparfait

> Albert Camus est mort accidentellement en 1960.

J'ai rencontré la variante :

> Albert Camus mourait accidentellement en 1960.

dans le livre [French Grammar in Context](https://www.routledge.com/French-Grammar-in-Context-4th-Edition/Jubb-Rouxeville/p/book/9780415706681) (p. 14). Les auteurs parlent de l'**imparfait de narration**. Quelle est la différence entre les deux propositions ? Je n'ai trouvé nulle part (du moins dans les autres livres de grammaire que je possède) ledit imparfait de narration. Est-ce un emploi particulier littéraire ?
Appartient-il en français courant ?
Par ailleurs, avec un verbe comme mourir il me semble bizarre l'emploi de l'imparfait.

NB Je connais les différences générales entre passé composé et imparfait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sans contexte, cela peut surprendre, mais l'imparfait peut être utilisé avec *mourir* comme *imparfait narratif* . L'imparfait narratif est plutôt utilisé dans le langage écrit, pour un effet dramatique.

Une bonne description et quelques exemples [en sont donnés par l'OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4197).

On peut utiliser cet imparfait lorsqu'on met en perspective des événements passés avec une indication précise de temps.

Regardez par exemple [cet article sur Albert Camus](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/culture/livres/50-ans-apres-sa-mort-albert-camus-fascine-toujours_1671341.html).
On y utilise l'imparfait pour évoquer l'événement précis de son décès:

> Il y a 50 ans jour pour jour, le 4 janvier 1960, mourait Albert Camus.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai rarement entendu le verbe mourir à l'imparfait lorsqu'on parle d'une personne individuelle ou d'un groupe bien identifié, il est plus courant d'utiliser le passé simple :

> Albert Camus **mourut** accidentellement en 1960.

Answer (score 2):

Le passé simple est le passé historique par excellence. Mais par effet de style on trouve **couramment** le présent de narration, voire l'imparfait qui est peut-être encore plus vivant, presque « cinématographique ». Tout dépend du style employé, du contexte.

> François Couperin, naquit le 10 novembre 1668 à Paris, il y mourut le
>   11 septembre 1733, ne laissant que deux messes pour orgue
>   – exceptionnelles – alors qu'il avait pratiqué cet instrument toute sa
>   vie ou presque.
>
> François Couperin, né le 10 novembre 1668 à Paris, meurt le 11
>   septembre 1733 ; il laisse le souvenir d'un claveciniste hors pair,
>   avec ses vingt-sept ordres de pièces de clavecin publiées en quatre
>   livres.
>
> Le 11 septembre 1733 mourait François Couperin, dit « le Grand ». De
>   santé fragile, il avait abandonné une à une ses charges diverses,
>   notamment à la Cour, à la Chapelle royale et à Saint-Gervais.

Comme on peut le lire, il n'y a pas franchement de différences de fait (dans tous les cas la date de sa mort est le 11 septembre 1733 !), mais de forme, de style.